# How to get dereferenced type of template member for function return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

How can I get the correct type `T` for the following function `to_vector`?

```
template<typename K> struct A { K* p; size_t n; std::string foo; };
template<typename K> struct B { K* p; size_t n; float bar[3]; };

template<typename X>
std::vector<T> to_vector(const X& x) {   // what is T?
    return std::vector<T>(x.p, x.p+x.n); 
}
```

I tried with `decltype(*std::declval<X>().p)` but this results in `error: forming pointer to reference type ‘float&’` for the following example:

```
A<float> a = { new float[10], 10, "hello" };
std::vector<float> v = to_vector(a);
```

This is part of some bigger code and there are more types like `A` and `B`. But all have a pointer `p` and a length `n`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can probably use

```
typename std::decay<decltype(*X::p)>::type
```

for `T` because `decltype` is an unevaluated context and hence `X::p` is legal here. Also, [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) seems like a good fit as it combines `std::remove_reference` with `std::remove_cv`.

Comment: `decay` isn't quite perfect if `K` is an C-style array type.  In that case, I'd want to convert the C-style array into a `std::array` most likely.  Probably a corner case that you don't care about (pointers to C-style arrays are not all that common).

Answer (score 6):

You are on the right track, you just need to use appropriate utility to get rid of the pointer/reference.

There is [`std::remove_reference`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/remove_reference/), which you can use like:

```
typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::declval<X>().p)>::type
```

but it's a bit simpler to [`std::remove_pointer`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/remove_pointer/) instead:

```
typename std::remove_pointer<decltype(std::declval<X>().p)>::type
```

(see, the `*` is gone, otherwise the same).

You might want to throw in [std::remove_cv](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/remove_cv/) into the mix if the pointer might be *cv*-qualified, because vector elements shouldn't be.

---

As noted in the other, now deleted answer, you can write `x.p` instead of `std::declval<X>().p` if you use the trailing return type declaration:

```
template <typename X>
auto to_vector(const X& x) ->
    std::vector<typename std::remove_pointer<decltype(x.p)>::type>
```

Comment: I think you need a `typename` there.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is pretty much obsolete now.

```
template<typename X, typename T = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*X().p)>::type>
std::vector<T> to_vector(const X& x)
{
    return std::vector<T>
         (x.p, x.p+x.n); 
}
```

Comment: This trailing return type doesn't add anything. You can equally write `std::vector<T> to_vector(const X& x)` as soon as you specified `T` using a template parameter with a default value like you did. The trailing return type makes sense if you don't want to add another template parameter `T` but specify the type "in place" (but this has the disadvantage that you have to do the same in the function body, like I saw in your edit history). So I'd simply use the normal return type syntax.

Comment: @leemes Yeah, whoops.

Comment: No your answer is not obsolete. The important thing is `remove_reference`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

So here is an answer completely out of left field.

You should turn your types `A` and `B` into iterable objects by overloading `begin` and `end` in their namespace.

There are multiple approaches for this:

1) You enforce that each of them implement a member-`begin` and member-`end` that returns a pointer as an iterator.  Alternatively a free function `begin` and `end` that does the same thing.

2) You require that they inherit from a CRTP helper class that does the above -- it either implements `begin` and `end` for you, or it enables a free function `begin` and `end` overload that can be seen with ADL.

3) If all such classes are in some `namespace` that you control, and you want to treat the `K* p` and `std::size_t n` fields as evidence that it should be treated as an iterable range, then we can do it with a "global" `begin` and `end` that uses SFINAE to only apply in that case.

I would advise #1 or #2.

For #2:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct p_n_iterable {
  Derived* self() {
    static_assert( std::is_base_of<p_n_iterable, Derived>::value, "CRTP failure" );
    return static_cast<Derived*>(this);
  }
  Derived const* self() const {
    static_assert( std::is_base_of<p_n_iterable, Derived>::value, "CRTP failure" );
    return static_cast<Derived const*>(this);
  }
  typedef typename std::decay< decltype( *Derived::p ) >::type value_type;
  typedef value_type* iterator;
  std::size_t size() const { return self()->n; }
  iterator begin() { return self->p; }
  iterator end() { return begin() + size(); }
};
```

if I wrote that right, change `A` to read:

```
template<typename K> struct A : p_n_iterable<A<K>> { ... unchanged ... };
```

and all of a sudden `for( auto x:a )` type loops work on `A`.

I think the cost, of having to add that little preamble to the classes, is so worth it for the feature.

To do this with #3, we create a `traits` class that detects if it should be `n_p_iterable` by checking that `T::n` is of type `std::size_t` and `T::p` is a pointer type.  I'd advise against this, for while it requires less boilerplate elsewhere, it is pretty hacky.

Once we have this, we can write a really generic `to_vector`.

To start with, we write ourself a `get_iterator_type<Container>`:

```
namespace adl_helper {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  template<typename C>
  auto adl_begin(C&& c)->decltype(begin( std::forward<C>(c) ));
  template<typename C>
  auto adl_end(C&& c)->decltype(end( std::forward<C>(c) ));
}
using adl_helper::adl_begin;
using adl_helper::adl_end;
template<typename... Ts> struct type_sink { typedef void type; }
template<typename... Ts> using TypeSink = typename type_sink<Ts...>::type;
template<typename Container, typename=void>
struct get_iterator_type {};
template<typename Container>
struct get_iterator_type< Container, TypeSink< adl_begin( std::declval<Container&>() ) > > {
  typedef adl_begin( std::declval<Container&>() ) type;
};
template<typename Container, typename=void>
struct get_value_type {};
template<typename Container>
struct get_value_type< Container, TypeSink< std::iterator_traits< typename get_iterator_type<Container>::type > > > {
  typedef std::iterator_traits< typename get_iterator_type<Container>::type > > traits;
  typedef typename traits::value_type type;
};
```

now, we write our `to_vector`:

```
template<typename C>
auto to_vector( C&& container )->
  std::vector<typename get_value_type<typename remove_reference<C>::type>::type>
{
  std::vector<typename get_value_type<typename remove_reference<C>::type>::type> retval;
  for( auto&& x : std::forward<C>(container) ) {
    retval.push_back(x);
  }
  return retval;
}
```

and if I dotted all the `i`s and crossed all the `t`s you now have both full C++11 style iteration on your types *and* a `to_vector` that works on both your types, and other iterable containers (such as a `std::map`).

Further improvements can include detecting if the container passed in has a `size` or has random-access iterators, and if so reserving size in `retval`.  But this post is long enough.

Comment: I have not gone to the bother of compiling the above, so it almost certainly contains syntax errors: if you are interested and want the `t`s crossed let me know, and I will spend the time to fix them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the long answer! In my case however I can not change A and B :( But in general that looks like a nice trick to get for-each compatibility on a user type.

Comment: @danvil #3 would still work.  You could even write a `to_range` function that converts your types to iterables, then feed that to `to_vector`.  I like ranged based `for`, and it often means you no longer need `to_vector` and the code runs faster and scales better.

Answer (score 0):

One can use traits :

```
template<typename K> struct A { K* p; size_t n; std::string foo; typedef K my_type; };
template<typename K> struct B { K* p; size_t n; float bar[3]; typedef K my_type; };

template<typename X>
std::vector<typename X::my_type> to_vector(const X& x) {  
    return std::vector<typename X::my_type>(x.p, x.p+x.n);
}

A<float> a = { new float[10], 10, "hello" };
std::vector<float> v = to_vector(a);
```